# Cocoa - Delete/remove items while parsing a NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, cocoa, parsing, nsmutablearray

I'd like to parse a `NSMutableArray`, and when I find some objects that respond to some conditions, I'd like to remove them from the array.

How may I do this without having two (or more) array for the process ?

For those who will be tempted to say : Hey, it's just impossible to parse AND remove objects from an array, I just can say that when I parse a drawer from which I want to remove out of date medicines, I do not have problem to do it... When I find one, I trash it, then I look for the next medicine box to check. I do not need a second drawer.

Comment: So as you're iterating through an array you want to remove objects from it. How do you expect to keep track of what's in the array if you're changing that same array on every iteration?

Comment: @Alex Reynolds : Uhhh, When I parse a bag from which I want to remove out of date medicines, I do not have problem to do it...

Comment: `NSMutableArray` is not a drawer of medicines. It has considerably more constraints. You will discover that this is the same with a lot of classes. For instance, `NSDocument` doesn't work like a tube of toothpaste.

Comment: @Rob Keniger : :-)  A tube of toothpaste  :-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a super elegant solution, that works with 2 arrays, ok, but that prevents to make a parsing loop in many situations ;

```
NSArray* matchingItems = [mainArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" attributetockeck MATCHES[cd] %@ ", attributevalue]];
[mainArray removeObjectsInArray:matchingItems];
```

Answer (score 6):

I use backward loop when I need to remove object from mutable array.

```
for (NSInteger i = arrayCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // remove is OK here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have 2 Arrays. Both of type `NSMUtableArray`. you can simply do -

`[mainArray removeObjectsInArray:toRemoveObjects];`

Answer (score 1):

I would copy the objects you want to keep into a new mutable array and assign the old array afterwards to the new array.

Answer (score 0):

```
for( NSUInter i = 0, j = 0; i < array.count; i++ )
{
    if( test )
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:j];
    else
        j++;
}
```

Here is the code in a command line version you can run and test yourself it removes every odd number

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool       * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray          * array = [NSMutableArray array];

    for( NSUInteger i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
        [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:random()%100]];


    NSLog( @"%@", array );

    for( NSUInteger i = 0, j = 0; i < array.count; i++ )
    {
        if( [[array objectAtIndex:j] unsignedIntegerValue] & 1 )
            [array removeObjectAtIndex:j];
        else
            j++;
    }   

    NSLog( @"%@", array );

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When removing items the array will get smaller en you code will crash

Comment: thats why I keep testing the array.count, i < array.count is executed every time though the loop so as the array gets small the value returned from array.count get smaller

Answer (score 0):

If you're validating the objects one at a time, you can use this instead:

```
[mainArray removeObject:objectToRemove];
```

Comment: It would help me, and anyone else following this question, if you'd post a code snippet showing how you're doing the validation and removal. There are several possible solutions, whether they work depends on how you're iterating through the entries.